# Query String to switch off parts of page

Tags: support, design

Are there any query strings to remove the right column and footer? (eg, `?hideFooter=1`)

[image]

I know I can run javascript to hide divs eg:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('categories').style.visibility='hidden';
```

However this question is about reducing the amount of HTML that is sent down the pipe. For example the page in the screenshot is a total 1406 lines of html..

Without Footer 1236
Without Hot Network Questions 1077
Without left column 926
Without Javascript 660

That's roughly 55% smaller.

To give you some context this is about processing Stackoverflow pages for automated lookup's *(not to create a duplicate site)*. Thats why using Javascript defeats the point as a WebClient or HttpWebRequest or whatever will download everything, hidden or not.

I also understand I can use the Stackoverflow API but that isn't what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the mobile view, scroll down to the footer and click "mobile":

[image]

This gives a much more cut-down full width view of the page. It doesn't change the URL, but appears to set the `theme` cookie for the site to `2` so I guess you could do this in a script.

[image]

Comment: Who downvoted? That's slack, this answer **is** useful.